# D'où vient « élu-e-s » ?

Tags: prononciation, orthographe, néologismes

J'ai remarqué récemment dans les tracts d'Europe Écologie, parfois ceux du PS et évidemment chez tou-te-s les militant-e-s féministes<sup>1</sup> l'habitude étrange d'ajouter -e- dans les adjectifs et les noms neutres. Comme s'ils étaient au masculin et que ne pas le rajouter était discriminatoire

Qui a inventé cette graphie ? Et comment la prononcent ceux qui l'utilisent ?

Question subsidiaire : même question pour *élu(e)s*

<sub>Sans polémique, par pitié</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Pour une certaine valeur de *tou-te-s*.</sub>

Comment: Voir aussi [Quel genre utiliser après « le » ou « la » ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1946/82).

Comment: Pff… +1 pour l'intérêt de la question, mais -14 pour faire de la publicité à cette horreur. Avec toute l'admiration que je peux porter aux féministes, c'est vraiment une des pires idé-E-S a-ux-la-quelle-S je les associe (`-E-S` *[sic]*, et *sick*, aussi, que ça me rend).

Comment: Le *Sans polémique, par pitié* est tout-à-fait cocasse. Nikana et moi nous retenons avec de grandes difficultés.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

J'ai peur de ne pas pouvoir répondre entièrement et avec exactitude à la question (qui? quand?)... Mais comme je suis à peu près sûr que la seule réponse présentement offerte est incorrect, je prends le temps de poster ces observations (en espérant que quelqu'un de plus calé sur le sujet nous offre une meilleure réponse):

1. Ce type d'usage (tout comme les parenthèses et autres) fait partie des types de rédaction dits *épicènes*, dont on trouve de nombreux guides sur Google (bizarrement, presque tous en pays francophones non-français). La plupart de ces guides administratifs "officiels" découragent l'utilisation de formes "élu(e)s" ou "élu-e-s" en raison de leur "lourdeur".
2. Comme je l'ai fait remarquer dans mon commentaire sur la réponse de @mouviciel, on trouve facilement des textes en-ligne antérieurs aux élections municipales de 2001, contenant cette graphie (et il me parait assez peu probable que le groupe de musique Zebda n'aient été les premiers à l'utiliser).
3. D'un point de vue purement anecdotique, j'ai clairement souvenir d'avoir vu la pratique vers la fin des années 90. D'habitude principalement sous la plume (/clavier) de personnes évoluant dans des mouvements non seulement féministes, mais souvent "[queer](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queer)"/transgenre. Malheureusement, je ne suis pas en mesure de retrouver des sources probantes en-ligne.
4. En revanche, [ce document sur les "bonnes" pratiques de rédaction épicène](http://www.ge.ch/egalite/doc/terminologie/redaction-epicene.pdf), de Suisse francophone, fait référence au début des années 2000 et précise au passage que le trait d'union devrait être préféré à la parenthèse afin "d'exprimer le féminin au même niveau que le masculin (on ne met pas la femme entre parenthèses)".
5. En France, pour des raisons qu'il ne semble pas franchement utile de décrire, les positions militantes féministes/LGBT sont plus souvent associés aux partis sus-cités (mouvements écologistes, PS, altermondialistes...), d'où la présence d'une telle graphie dans leurs communications.

Answer (score 1):

La popularisation de la forme avec traits d'unions vient de Toulouse et de Zebda. C'était une liste électorale des municipales de mars 2001 qui s'appelait les [Motivé-e-s](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motiv%C3%A9-e-s).

J'ai remarqué que l'utilisation des traits d'union plutôt que les traditionnelles parenthèses indiquait une sympathie politique aux mouvances de gauche de type écologiste ou altermondialiste.

Comment: A noter que qu'ils écrivent également [les élue-e-s](http://www.motive-e-s.org/le_site/accueil.php3) et non les élu-e-s.

Comment: Sans connaître les origines exactes de la forme, je suis à peu près certain (pour avoir vu leur utilisation dans ces milieux à l'époque) qu'elles sont plus en rapport avec des courants féministes ou "queer" que écologistes/altermondialistes, même s'il y a un lien naturel avec ces derniers. L'explication Zebda me paraît *très* douteuse. Voir au hasard [ce lien](http://dunautregenre.xooit.com/t304-Developper-des-competences-avec-des-patient-e-s-transsexuel-le-s-et-transgenres-Soins-generaux-et-prescriptions-d-hormones.htm) antérieur d'une année à la dite-liste.

Comment: @Dave - Sans nier la possibilité que Zebda n'ait fait que populariser la forme (j'ai modifié ma réponse en ce sens), la plus ancienne date mentionnée sur le lien en question est 2006 et la date citée dans le guide de rédaction épicène est juin 2001.