# Quel genre utiliser après « le ou la » ?

Tags: genre

J'aimerais écrire ceci:

> … le ou la participant(e) …

mais je ne suis pas sûr du genre à utiliser pour *participant(e)*. J'aurais tendance à utiliser la version féminine, donc participante, mais je trouve ça un peu bizarre également.

Comment: Voir aussi [D'où vient « élu-e-s » ?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/1378)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Il a existé [la règle ou accord de proximité](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A8gle_de_proximit%C3%A9), qui fait que *le ou la participante* s'explique. Selon cette règle on accorde un mot avec la marque de genre la plus proche. Mais cette règle est passée, est aujourd'hui fautive, à ce que je comprends.

D'après les québécois, il vaut mieux dire *la ou le participant*. Et, comme le dit Evpok, d'après l'Académie, le masculin est neutre.

Comment: Merci pour la référence à la règle. Je n'aime pas trop la tournure avec le féminin à l'avant par contre. J'irai peut-être donc avec le masculin uniquement.

Comment: J'aime bien *la ou le*, qui — change et — met le féminin en avant, tout en gardant la forme générique masculine, conformément à une règle qui avait du bon sens. Dommage qu'on ne puisse favoriter que des questions.

Answer (score 4):

En ce qui me concerne, j'écrirais simplement

> […] le participant […]

et j'éviterais ces orthographes [soi-disant épicènes](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1378/82). Je rappelle que le masculin est en français la forme non-marquée [d'après l'Académie](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/langue/questions.html#feminisation) et s'emploie quand le genre est indéterminé

> Seul le genre masculin, non marqué, peut représenter aussi bien les éléments masculins que féminins. En effet, le genre féminin ou marqué est privatif : un « groupe d’étudiantes » ne pourra contenir d’élèves de sexe masculin, tandis qu’un « groupe d’étudiants » pourra contenir des élèves des deux sexes, indifféremment. On se gardera également de dire les électeurs et les électrices […] expressions qui sont non seulement lourdes mais aussi redondantes, les informaticiennes étant comprises dans les informaticiens. De la même manière, l’usage du symbole « / » ou des parenthèses pour indiquer les formes masculine et féminine […] doit être proscrit dans la mesure où il contrevient à la règle traditionnelle de l’accord au pluriel.

Comment: J'ai vu moult formulaires québecois avec l'excellente note de bas de page « *Le générique masculin est utilisé sans discrimination et uniquement dans le but d'alléger le texte.* », dont j'espère qu'elle satisfait toutes les susceptibilités. Sans, je sais le masculin générique, mais j'accorde quand même plus d'importance à l'effacement de certaines discriminations, dont cette règle n'est qu'un peu de poudreuse au dessus de l'iceberg.

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Bof. Si on se sent offensé quand il n'y pas cette note c'est soit qu'on est ignorant soit qu'on a envie de se sentir insulté. Dans les deux cas je trouve ça triste.

Comment: Sans aller jusqu'à se sentir offensé (bien heureusement, les sentiments humains ont plus de nuances…), on peut souhaiter que le féminin plus pris en compte, et moins sous-représenté. Même si c'est grammaticalement inutile, si ça peut avoir un impact social positif, alors d'après moi c'est bon à prendre, voire peut valoir le coup d'être revendiqué, etc.