# Le pronom « they » au singulier et la référence au genre ?

Tags: traduction, pronoms, genre

En anglais, j'utilise de plus en plus le pronom « [they](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they) » au singulier pour rendre des exemples inclusifs et non pas centrés sur le [genre](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lesbiennes,_gays,_bisexuels_et_transgenres) (« *the person left, but I think they forgot [their](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/48) books* » - au lieu de formes [duelles](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1378) comme « *he/she* left, but I think *he/she* forgot *his/her* books »)<sup>1</sup>. Dans un [article](http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/montreal/bry-bitar-montreal-lgbt-teen-sparks-school-uniform-revolution-1.3002403) en anglais, je lis ce qui suit:

> When I first met Bry Bitar, I assumed they were 17 years old, but it
>   turns out Bry is a tall, charming 13-year-old.
>
> And yes, Bry prefers the pronoun "they" — not he or she. Bry also
>   prefers to avoid labels.

*Google* [translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=en&tl=fr&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cbc.ca%2Fnews%2Fcanada%2Fmontreal%2Fbry-bitar-montreal-lgbt-teen-sparks-school-uniform-revolution-1.3002403&edit-text=) ne semble pas en mesure d'identifier le pronom dans sa forme au singulier et rend donc érronément au pluriel.

Comment peut-on traduire cet **extrait** en français (pronoms personnels, et les adjectifs dans une moindre mesure) de manière intégrée et neutre ? Subsidiairement, si une institution de la francophonie s'est penchée sur la question, on pourrait le mentionner, le cas échéant.

---

<sub>1. Dans d'autres [contextes](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3956), on tente de rendre toute *l'ampleur sémantique* d'un concept.</sub>

Comment: Il s'agit là de deux questions. À la première la réponse est « elle » tout simplement parce que le pronom renvoie à la *personne*, qui est un mot féminin. Pour la seconde question…

Comment: +1 j'ai appris un truc en Anglais.

Comment: Not convinced enough about this to go beyond a comment, but my French wife claims that her gender, i.e., the feminine one, is the only gender in French deserving of its own forms (feminine forms…. I like) and that all the other, non-deserving genders (masculine, neuter, etc) are all grouped together in one non-feminine form by default, so actually using the non-feminine forms is gender neutral…..go figure.

Comment: Je ne comprends pas la question. Elle suppose vraisemblablement de comprendre le *pourquoi* de cette tentative d'inventer une version alternative du français qui ne fasse pas référence au genre. De plus, le titre est trompeur, même si j'avoue qu'il est parfois difficile d'être concis et complet dans cet espace réduit. Cela dit pour rester constructif face à ce qu'il me semble difficile d'appeler un problème. La langue française intègrera cette forme progressivement si elle correspond à quelque chose, mais en attendant cela semble voué à rester un souhait un peu vain...

Comment: (J'ai retiré en deuxième lecture le -1 que j'avais mis spontanément au premier passage. Les liens sont pertinents, la formulation est très bonne et montre une vraie interrogation, soutenue par une recherche préalable sur le sujet)

Answer (score 2):

Je dirais *on* tout simplement, c'est apersonnel et ni masculin ni féminin, comme le *they* anglais.

Comment: J'ai cru qu'on avait 17 ans (...) Et oui, Bry préfère le pronom "on", pas "il" ou "elle".

Comment: Le seul problème, qui n'est pas forcément très grave, c'est que *on* a déjà [d'autres conotations](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/4603/79), bien différentes.

Comment: Bry préfère ?! Est-ce suffisant pour modifier un langage ?

Comment: @Romain l'usage de *they* comme pronom de genre neutre remonte à Shakespeare et même avant. On peut difficulement parler de "modifier". La question demeure pertinente en français, puisque l'attitude *genderqueer* ne se retrouve pas que dans la sphère anglophone.

Comment: @Circeus Je parlais de la langue française, qui utilise le genre masculin pour les cas neutres. C'est une donnée arbitraire de la langue, en effet, comme nombre d'autres. Je n'y vois ni sexisme ni oppression linguistique d'aucun groupe de personnes, ni aucun "problème" à résoudre.

Comment: @RomainVALERI Au contraire. Dans la mesure où il y a réellement des gens qui se réclame du droit de ne se faire assigner aucun genre, il s'agit sans le moindre doute (du moins de leur point de vue) d'un "problème à résoudre". Et un problème passablement épineux, qui plus est.

Comment: @Circeus *des gens qui se réclament du droit de ne se faire assigner aucun genre* ? Un *droit*, vraiment ? Est-ce le bon terme ici ? Il ne suffit pas de souhaiter quelque chose pour en faire un droit. Ni le langage ni le contrat social n'obéissent à la loi du marché, il ne suffit pas qu'il y ait une demande. Il serait aussi absurde et arbitraire d'inventer un prétendu *droit à assigner un genre aux autres*... (bref, je suis désolé, ce n'est pas le lieu pour en débattre je le sais bien)

Comment: @Circeus, le problème est qu'il ne faut pas confondre genre grammatical et sexe biologique ou social. Aucun macho, aussi misogyne fût-il, n'a jamais objecté d'être appelé _une personne_ ni ne s'est plaint de l'utilisation subséquente des pronoms féminins qui en découle.

Answer (score 2):

À ma connaissance, il n'y a pas de correspondance, de terme *officiel* en français, mais plusieurs associations, organismes et militant-e-s trans* penchent vers le terme *ille* (contraction du il et du elle).

Comment: Merci! Si je dis "Ille est +adjectif", quel accord ou graphie suggère-t-on pour l'accord de l'adjectif dans ce contexte? Y a-t-il une organisation qui élabore sur le sujet dans un document en particulier?

Answer (score 1):

My normally trusty source of French stands by her claim that gender neutrality already exists in French and [that using the non-feminine forms of pronouns and adjectives is actually gender neutral](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13436/le-pronom-they-au-singulier-et-la-r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence-au-genre#comment25413_13436), so I’m on my own with the following observations (and translation near the end):

I’ve also noticed/used the singular “they” that you mention, but in my experience it generally is introduced/prefaced at least once by using  the gender neutral “the/that person” or “the/that individual” before switching to “they/their” (just as you’ve done in the first paragraph of your question: « the person left, but I think they forgot their books »).

The passage about Bry, however, jumps right to “they” without that clear “person”/”individual” warning that generally helps my ears and brain prepare for the singular “they,” which can only mean that my experience is obviously as old-school as my ears and brain.  I still feel, however, that setting the stage for singular “theys” by first mentioning the word “person” or “individual” is a defensible middle-ground in English.

French, of course, has its own gender (sexual)-neutral versions of both “person” and “individual” and I think that using a balanced, alternating combination of these two words to replace gender specific pronouns might be a suitable middle-ground position in French as well.

Avoiding subsequent reference by pronouns would, of course, help keep the discussion more gender-neutral both grammatically and sexually, but all concerned should try to make the effort to understand that subsequent references by pronouns  and adjectives would be derived from the grammatic gender of the words “personne” and “individu” and not from the actual person’s or individual’s sex.

To the extent that feminine-form pronouns and adjectives referring to and describing “cette personne” and masculine-form pronouns/adjectives referring to and describing “cet individu” might be incorrectly confused (or purposely ignored as inadequate) as referring to the person’s/individual’s sex and not simply to the grammatic gender of these two gender-neutral words, perhaps systematically alternating between them during the course of a discussion could remove, or at least blur the gender labels.

So in your passage, I’d propose (and please [feel free to] excuse my French errors to the extent that they don’t render my translation incomprehensible):

> Quand j’ai rencontré Bry Bitar, j’ai cru que cette personne avait 17
>   ans, mais en fait cet individu [si] charmant, cette personne [si]
>   grande n’a que 13 ans.
>
> Et oui, Bry préfère se décrire avec les mots *personne* ou *individu*
>   plutôt qu'avec *homme*, *femme* ou n’importe quel mot qui attribue une
>   constitution ou « étiquette » génétique aux gens.

Frankly, when I see how the issue of avoiding civil status labels for over half of the population was addressed in 'Francophonia' (i.e., by defaulting to an existing title, Madame, as opposed to creating/resurrecting a status-neutral title as was done in English with *Ms* (not an abbreviation of Miss, btw) and in light of the hard-fought struggle to ADD gender-specific endings to words/professions that had previously defaulted invariably to one gender or the other, I am inclined to believe that this issue will likewise be addressed, not by neologisms, but by defaulting to existing words and grammar rules and theories (as my wife’s) already in place.

(Regardless, the status quo surely beats resorting to using the French equivalent of the pejorative “it” [“Ça”?], which far too many of my bigoted com‘patriots’ use to avoid giving credence and recognition to the singular “they” and value to the individuals represented thereby.)

Comment: Thank you! That's very well put and interesting. Using "personne" would have been my reflex too. I find alternating between individu and personne to hook both masc. and fem. for the adjectives was really clever, despite making it all somewhat heavier. It is challenging, thanks again!