# Désigner une personne sans révéler son genre

Tags: pronoms, genre

En anglais, quand on veut référer à une personne sans révéler son genre, on utilise « they » au lieu de « he » ou « she ».

Est-ce qu'il y a une tournure équivalente en français ?

Comment: je ne comprend pas: "they" c'est pour le pluriel !

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET Non, "they" est régulièrement utilisé au singulier pour des référents inconnus ou indéfinis et, de plus en plus, pour des référents connus. "I know Ted; they're really into rock" est grammatical pour certains anglophones, mais pas tous.

Comment: Oh, et "appeler une personne" veut dire "to call someone". "Se référer à quelqu'un" ou "parler de quelqu'un" seraient plus appropriés pour l'intitulé de cette question

Comment: Voir aussi http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13436/le-pronom-they-au-singulier-et-la-r%C3%A9f%C3%A9rence-au-genre

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET *Singular they* sur [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53249/singular-they-and-gender-neutrality), sur [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they), et un article de la très honorable [*American Dialect Society*](http://www.americandialect.org/2015-word-of-the-year-is-singular-they) qui montre que cet usage de *they* pour éviter de donner le sexe d'une personne est très ancien et évolue, comme le dit Eau qui dort, jusqu'à être désormais employé pour parler d'une personne connue.

Comment: C'est hors sujet mais il est intéressant de noter que l'emploi de _they_ au singulier n'autorise pas nécessairement celui de _themself_ en langue anglaise dans _This is the first step in helping someone to help themselves._ (ça vaut le singulier ici) ; [_ODO_](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/themselves-or-themself) indique que le tour avec _themself_ n'est pas accepté de tous et ne recommande pas son emploi dans un registre formel à l'écrit.

Comment: Il faut bien savoir où placer ce they de non-révélation du genre. //Themself n'existe pas. Themselves. C'est la première fois de ma vie que je vois ce mot.

Comment: [Themself](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/themself), [themselves](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/themselves).

Answer (score 5):

Il est possible d'utiliser une dénomination abstraite pour désigner la femme ou l'homme en question.

> Cette personne que je connais, elle a fait ceci ou bien cela ...

Ici on parle de la personne mais on ne sait pas s'il s'agit d'un homme ou d'une femme...

Idem avec :

> L'individu en question, ...

Même si cette formulation semble dénuée d'affectivité, elle serait utilisée par la police par exemple afin de décrire des faits de façon très neutre.

Comment: Et *la personne*...

Answer (score 4):

Tu peux dire "quelqu'un" (un masculin qui peut designer les 2 sexes) ou "une/cette personne" (un féminin qui peut designer les 2 sexes).
Ou "on" (somebody).

Comment: Pour etre neutre de genre, si j'utilise "quelqu'un", comment puis-je referer a la meme personne plus tart? Merci!

Comment: @Dxml you would say *cette personne* (maybe in some rare cases *ce quelqu'un* but I would not recommend it). Maybe it would be a good idea to sometimes use the masculine "quelqu'un" and sometimes the feminine "une/la/cette personne" in order to maintain the ambiguity.

Comment: @Law29 Personnellement je me méfie de cet usage de "on", car ce pronom a désormais pour énormément de personne le sens par défaut de "nous". Ça ne m'offusque pas en soit, mais il m'est arrivé de voir des phrases où il avait les deux sens, et le résultat n'est pas très réussi.

Comment: @Circeus Tu prêches à un convaincu... même si ça ne m'offusque pas en soi !

Comment: @Circeus: du coup le "ils" tend a remplacer le "on", ce qui donne l'impression un peu complotiste d'un groupe connu qu'on ne nomme pas, tandis que le "on" etait pratiquement aussi indetermine' qu'un passif.

Answer (score 3):

Il n'y a pas de réel équivalent au *they* singulier en français et d'une manière générale, il est impossible de parler très longtemps d'une personne sans lui assigner un genre grammatical.

L'anglais a presque totalement perdu le genre au sens grammatical, ce qui laisse le loisir aux locuteurs d'utiliser les pronoms (rare reliques qui changent encore selon leur genre) pour assigner ou refuser d'assigner un genre sémantique à quelqu'un. A contrario, le genre grammatical est bien trop robuste en français pour permettre ce genre de permutation.

De même, lorsque l'agent d'un verbe est indéfini et inconnu, on s'y réfère généralement au masculin et à la troisième personne du singulier. La traduction de "If somebody comes in, they'll be very surprised" est donc "Si quelqu'un rentre, il sera fort surpris".

Et à l'oral, lorsqu'un sujet indéfini est doublé par un pronom clitique, c'est toujours *il* qui est choisi. Dans mon exemple ci-dessus, ça donnerait "Si quelqu'un il rentre, ..."

Un anglicisme que j'ai remarqué dans mon usage de la langue est que je me réfère parfois à des personnes inconnues au pluriel. J'avais initialement écrit la fin de mon premier paragraphe comme "sans **leur** assigner un genre grammatical" ! Mais même si la pratique se répand, elle n'affectera que le nombre et pas le genre.

Comment: Merci @eau qui dort pour ta reponse tres detaille. Je suis d'accord qu'on utilise "il" la plupart du temps pour un sujet indefini et inconnu, meme en anglais parfois. 

Toutefois, lorqu'on veut eviter d'etre percu involontairement comme un 'masculinist' (je ne suis pas sur s'il y a un mot francais equivalent pour ce mot-ci), speciallement dans l'epoque actuelle avec la connaissance de l'egalite des genres, on utilise "she" ou "they" pour referer a un sujet un inconnu et/ou indefini. 

Est-ce qu'on fait quelque chose de similaire en francais?
e.g. Si quelqu'un rentre, ELLE sera fort surpris.

Comment: @Dxml C'est envisageable, mais d'un usage assez délibéré. J'ai déjà entendu ça dans des discours ou dans des présentations, mais jamais spontanément (ce qui ne veut pas dire qu'il n'y ait pas quelqu'un quelque part qui parle comme ça dans une conversation de tous les jours, juste que ça n'est pas très répandu)

Comment: les militants abusent de formules "il-elle" et autre bi-accords avec des -e- au milieu des mots. c'est assez lourd. ce qui est triste aussi, c'est que ça fabrique du genre là où en fait il n'y en avait pas (que le neutre français ressemble souvent au masculin ne veut pas dire qu'il est masculin). Bref une connaissance superficielle de la grammaire à introduit de la politisation là où elle n'avait pas lieu d'être (et ensuite on se persuade de la voir partout).

Comment: En neo-zelandais, le neutre est parfois feminin, par exemple pour le temps qu'il fait, ou "she'll be 'right" pour "ça va aller".