# Comment peut-on décrire les actions d'un individu sans préciser son sexe ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, genre, déterminants

Comment pourrait-on décrire les actions qu'une personne accomplit en prenant soin de ne pas préciser son sexe (masculin, féminin ou autre) dans le but d'être le plus neutre possible et sans utiliser de néologismes ?

Je ne sais pas quoi utiliser en français, surtout en ce qui concerne les déterminants, pour écrire un texte de la sorte sans que cela ne soit ennuyeux à la lecture.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18182/d%c3%a9signer-une-personne-sans-r%c3%a9v%c3%a9ler-son-genre/18191#18191

Comment: L'écriture inclusive peut permettre de résoudre certains problèmes (bien que sa légitimité soit sujette à débat dans la société), et si cela entrave trop la lecture, utiliser des sujets vagues du type "cette personne", "quelqu'un", "on", puis accorder le reste des phrases en accord.